# Keep getting this error in Ruby on Rails: rake aborted! NameError: uninitialized constant Faker::Coffee

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to re-seed an existing Ruby on Rails application. Before, this exact same seed file worked but after db:dropping, db:creating, db:migrating, I can no longer seed my database using the db:seed. I keep getting this error, 
"NameError: uninitialized constant Faker::Coffee"
I am using the Faker gem to populate my database and I used that successfully before, have bundle installed and updated my gemfile, but still no luck. Scoured this site and web but have found no solutions so far. Tried to not use faker and simply seed data using my own names but still got the same error as above, just with the name I wanted to use. I am stuck, any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my seed file for reference:

```
  b = Menu.create(name: 'Breakfast')
  l = Menu.create(name: 'Lunch')
  d = Menu.create(name: 'Dinner')
  ln = Menu.create(name: 'Late Night')

  def add_menu_items(menu)
  10.times do
  menu.menu_items.create(
  name: Faker::Coffee.blend_name,
  description: Faker::Coffee.notes,
  price: Faker::Number.between(5.50, 100.75)
  )
 end
end

add_menu_items(b)
add_menu_items(l)
add_menu_items(d)
add_menu_items(ln)

puts 'Menus Seeded'
```

Comment: Did you `bundle install` ? It looks like the Faker gem is not recgonized

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried bundle install on old computer and for whatever reason, old computer would not let anything with Faker or own seed methods work. Ran app on newer computer, did a bundle install/update and everything worked.